# Tried to generate the code using Jooq using SQL Server but not able to do so

Tags: java, sql, gradle, jooq

Have Tried to generate the code using Jooq using SQL Server configuration in gradle but not able to do so.But the same thing is working fine with h2DB.
Can anyone please explain to me how to generate the classes for mssql server using jooq in gradle.

```
**Here is my gradle code:**

import org.jooq.util.jaxb.*
import org.jooq.util.*

buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.186'   
    classpath 'org.jooq:jooq-codegen:3.9.1' 
    classpath 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:4.0' 
   classpath "io.ratpack:ratpack-gradle:0.9.7-SNAPSHOT"
    classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:1.0.2'

  }
}
plugins {
  id 'io.ratpack.ratpack-java' version '1.3.3'
}

repositories {
  jcenter()
}

dependencies {
  compile ratpack.dependency('hikari') 
  compile 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.186' 
  compile 'org.jooq:jooq:3.9.1' 
  compile 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:4.0' 
  compile "io.ratpack:ratpack-gradle:0.9.7-SNAPSHOT"
  compile 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:1.0.2'

}
mainClassName = 'App'

task jooqCodegen {
  doLast {
    String init = "<directory>/init.sql"
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration()
      .withJdbc(new Jdbc()
      .withDriver("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver") 
      .withUrl("jdbc:sqlserver://<server address>;DatabaseName=JOOQ; INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM '$init'") 
      .withUser("****")
      .withPassword("****")
    )
      .withGenerator(new Generator()
        .withDatabase(new Database()
         .withName("org.jooq.util.sqlserver.SQLServerDatabase")
          .withIncludes(".*")
          .withExcludes("")
          .withInputSchema("dbo")
        )
      .withTarget(new Target()
        .withDirectory("$projectDir/src/main/java") 
        .withPackageName("jooq"))) 
    GenerationTool.generate(configuration)
  }
}

**Note :** Added one create table statement in init.sql file
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The jOOQ Open Source Edition does not support SQL Server [as shown here](https://www.jooq.org/legal/licensing/#databases). In order to use the jOOQ Professional Edition with gradle, you will need to make the following adaptations:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'org.jooq.pro:jooq-codegen:3.9.1' 
    // ...
  }
}
// ...

dependencies {
  compile 'org.jooq.pro:jooq:3.9.1' 
  // ...
}
```

Notice that the Maven `groupId` has changed. These are all the available `groupId` values for the different jOOQ editions:

- `org.jooq` for the Open Source Edition (available from Maven Central)
- `org.jooq.pro` for commercial editions (not available from Maven Central)
- `org.jooq.pro-java-6` for commercial editions with Java 6 support (not available from Maven Central)
- `org.jooq.trial` for the free trial edition (not available from Maven Central)

Comment: Thank you for your help!